# I would like to check values as they are entered in the text box? I have used onBlur() event for that, but the code is not executing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am providing the code. Please tell me what is wrong. I used an an `onBlur()` event with the textbox but the red alert is not coming on the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function hasValue(fname)
    {
         var input = document.licence.fname;

        if (input == "" ) 
        {
                showErrorMessage(input, "value required");
                return false;
        } 
        else {
                
                return true;
        }
    }
    
    function showErrorMessage(input,"value required")
    {
        var msg_text = document.createElement("span");
        msg_text.textContent = "value required";
        msg_text.style.color = "red";
        input.parentNode.insertBefore(msg_text,input.nextSibling);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation of the problem in the question, *not* the title.

Comment: msg_text.innerHTML = "value required";

Comment: function showErrorMessage() is not getting executed as I move between the text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest that you use jQuery:

```
$(".inputElementClass").blur(function(){ 

//Do what you need to do...

});
```

In regular old javascript:

```
blurMe = document.getElementsByClassName(".blurClass"); 

blurMe.addEventListener("blur", function() {

//Do what you need to do. 

 }, true);
```

Comment: This is my assignment and I have to use javaScript for it. Is there anyway this can be executed in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The code you entered is difficult to read so a JSfiddle would be helpful but first onBlur() triggers when an element loses focus so if you want to check it 'as they are entered' you would need to use .keyup or .keypress or .keydown

They all work slightly differently so you can look up the specifics and choose which one you want.

edit -- ok the code got formatted as I was typing this :)

This is one i am using for calling the function

**1.What is your name**

```
    <p> <b>Surname </b></p>
    <input type="text" id="sname" name="sname"  /> 


    <p> <b>Full first Name </b></p>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name=" fname"  size="50" onblur="hasValue('fname')"/>


    <p> <b>Middle Names </b></p>
    <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname"  size="50" />
```

Comment: The onBlur event only triggers when the user leaves the input box, like if they tab to the next box or click on something else.  It doesn't trigger as they type.  Could you post the code you are using to call these functions.

Comment: <p><b> 1.What is your name</b></p>
    
     <p> <b>Surname </b></p>
     <input type="text" id="sname" name="sname"  /> 
    
    
     <p> <b>Full first Name </b></p>
     <input type="text" id="fname" name=" fname"  size="50" onblur="hasValue('fname')"/>
    
    
     <p> <b>Middle Names </b></p>
     <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname"  size="50" />